# Restoring database from SSMS UI freezes SSMS

Tags: ssms

I am using SSMS 17.3. I try to restore a database from the UI, click on 'Device' radio button and click on the ... to select a file, SSMS freezes. I have to kill it. I have to restore databases using SQL.

Any ideas why it freezes?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: I'm also having this issue with  SSMS 18.0 (GA).

Comment: I may have just stumbled upon the answer... This may be an old known issue.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/sql-server-2012-restore-wizard-freezes I've just tried it and it worked for me (using SSMS 18).